# components and Input() setting properties

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular 6 and when learning how to pass data from a parent component into a child component it was shown that we should add an Input() property into the child which is what the parent will populate.

My question was, if i'm just creating a component with a property, like elementId, that it going to be set when i use the element.  It will not be passed into it from another component, but hardcoded like:

```
<my-component elementId='xyz'>
```

the guide i'm seeing is creating that elementId as an Input() in the component.  I thought earlier guides i read never did that, it was just declared as a regular property in the component class, without the Input()

Is the Input() always needed, or just when passing data from parent into child?

I have included the code the author used:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-modal',
  templateUrl: './simple-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple-modal.component.css']
})
export class SimpleModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() elementId: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  closeModal() {

  }

}
```

Component is used within another component as:

```
<simple-modal elementId="searchResults" title="Matching Sessions">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let session of foundSessions" [routerLink]="['/events', session.eventId]">{{session.name}}</a>
  </div>
</simple-modal>
```

Comment: How are you planning on accessing `elementId` inside `my-component` if you don't use `@Input()`?

Comment: OP says that fields with the same names will be populated @Input but not bound.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use Angular 7 (soon to be Angular 8)?

Comment: If i add [] around the title or elementId the code errors, else it works

Comment: @Zze I want to use it but i wanted to know why the its not [elementId]? The examples i saw earlier using @Input() always have the attribute in [] but not here

Comment: @theMayer only becuase the guide im using was using that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input allows you to do bindings in template (in HTML markup, not in OOP manner). They are updated in async way and updating such input will invoke `onChange` callback. You cant have that with simple property.

EDIT:

Out of curiosity I have checked your statement and the answer is NO, it wont be set.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtkgt4

Comment: but without @Input() the elementId would still populate correct? just it won't happen async and not trigger the onChange.  as i've seen examples where properties were used without Input().  that's why I was trying to figure out why it was done that way, otherwise i've only seen it when parents are passing values ot children

Comment: I found this which explains it as well:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets

Comment: I have included the author's code, i'm still curious why it works, and when i add [] around the elementId and title attributes it errors with a template error.

Comment: @Paritosh there are @Input() annotation everywhere in that code you have provided.

Comment: When you use `elementId="sometext"` than it is equal to `[elementId]="'sometext'"`. When you use `[]` then whats following is expected to be an expression, while without brackets it will be threated as simple string. @Input is required in both cases. Moreover, in code you have quoted, @Inputs are used in contrary to what you have stated.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where the answer is "because that's what the documentation says."

Angular requires the `Input()` directive for template binding to component properties. Angular does not make a distinction between a "hard-coded" value and a dynamic value. If you want to supply the value of a child component from a template parent, you have to use `Input()` decorator.

Frankly, even if you could get away without the `Input()` decorator, this would almost certainly be a programming mistake and would be horrible design practice.

Answer (score 0):

**The [`@Input`](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding) decorator will create a binding for the property** (in your case elementId), therefore it will be checked in every change detection cycle.

If your **property will never change, there is an alternative: `@Attribute` decorator**, which is read just once.

You may use it this way:

```
import { Component, Attribute } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<label>{{ elementId }}</label>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(@Attribute('elementId') public elementId: string) { }
}
```